# How to don't add type of script tag in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, ejs, html-webpack-plugin

Actual W3C standard says that it should be not **type="text/javascript"** in your  tag. So in Webpack, inside of HtmlWebpackPlugin I use following settings:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    faviconhash: Date.now(),
    template: 'index.ejs',
    filename: '../index.html',
    hash: true
})
```

What I get is HTML file that is good but it contains unwanted type parameter in my script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js?15d322717ae8d7527f79"></script>
```

What I want is simply:

```
<script src="js/app.js?15d322717ae8d7527f79"></script>
```

How can I achieve that?

PS: This is the message from W3C HTML Validator:

> Warning: The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.

Comment: Any specific reason why you need **only** the `script` tag?

Comment: I want to have validate website by W3C HTML Validator.

Comment: The official MIME type is `application/javascript`, so I can understand why it's failing. But you shouldn't be putting this much work in something which is totally redundant.

Comment: There is an open issue for that: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/835

Comment: Referring to [this](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type) link, it says that it's perfectly valid.

Comment: So for current moment only think I can do is to wait for HtmlWebpackPlugin update?

Comment: @weirdpanda So https://validator.w3.org is wrong?

Comment: You can see it says `unnecessary`; not `incorrect`. Referring to that link again, it's by W3 again. The official (i.e., corrected) MIME type as of ECMA262 is `text/javascript`. It points out a redundancy, not something malformed.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to don't have any warnings :)

Comment: Ah, alright. One thing I can think of is to filter the part in the plugin itself and hardwire it to remove it. You can, then, update the code and create a PR for the linked issue. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164399/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-edenwave).

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file `index.js` and go to line 479 and remove it.

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L479